# Slider Entrance Left, exit left

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider

thanks for checking out my question.

All I am trying to do is this, Have a slide enter from the left side and exit to the left side. 
I am building a site on WP and no amount of plugins or hand-code seems to be able to solve this.

I have a few digital composites for my slides that I have attached below, All I want them to do is slide in from the left side of the screen, and exit to the left side of the screen individually.

Thanks for reading, hope the image below works so you can see what I am trying to accomplish, working on WP and Elementor. No widget, 3rd party plugin seems to have what I would consider a standard feature, the ability to set entrance and exit direction.

https://ibb.co/k8XCrqq

[Graphic illustration of slider](https://ibb.co/k8XCrqq)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do. You can use CSS transition to do that. Here is an example of a left sidebar. When you click the sidebar, the sidebar will slide to the left.

```js
$(".page-sidebar").on("click",function(){
   $(this).addClass("sidebar-close");
});
```

```css
.page-sidebar{
  width: 260px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  background: #161931;
}
.page-sidebar.sidebar-close{
  left:-260px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-sidebar">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will give it a try, is there a way to automate this? without the need for click?